# Missed row when running SELECT with READCOMMITTEDLOCK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a T-SQL code that delta-copies data from the source table (SrcTable) to the destination table (DestTable). The data is inserted into the source table by multiple sessions and copied to the destination table by a SQL Server Agent job.
Here's the snippet which inserts the batch into the destination table:

```
...

WITH cte
AS (SELECT st.SrcTable_ID,
           st.SrcTable_CreatedDateTime
    FROM SrcTable st WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK, INDEX(PK_SrcTable))
    WHERE st.SrcTable_ID
    BETWEEN @FromID AND @ToID)
INSERT DestTable
(
    DestTable_SrcTableID
)
SELECT cte.SrcTable_ID
FROM cte;

...
```

both tables are partitioned on `CreatedDateTime` column which default to `SYSUTCDATETIME`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SrcTable](
    [SrcTable_ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SrcTable_CreatedDateTime] [DATETIME2](3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SrcTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SrcTable_ID] ASC,
    [SrcTable_CreatedDateTime] ASC
) ON [ps_Daily]([SrcTable_CreatedDateTime])
) ON [ps_Daily]([SrcTable_CreatedDateTime])
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DestTable](
    [DestTable_ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DestTable_CreatedDateTime] [DATETIME2](3) NOT NULL,
    [DestTable_SrcTableID] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DestTable_ID] ASC,
    [DestTable_CreatedDateTime] ASC
) ON [ps_Daily]([DestTable_CreatedDateTime])
) ON [ps_Daily]([DestTable_CreatedDateTime])
GO
```

This code has been running for years copying millions of records a day with no issues.
Recently it started missing a single row every couple of weeks.

Here's an example of such a batch with `@FromID=2140` and `@ToID=2566` and one missing row (2140)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SrcTable st
LEFT JOIN dbo.DestTable dt ON st.SrcTable_ID=dt.DestTable_SrcTableID
WHERE st.SrcTable_ID BETWEEN 2140 AND 2566
ORDER BY st.SrcTable_ID ASC
```

[image: the result set of the LEFT JOIN]

The only plausible explanation that I can think of is that the allocation of identity values (SrcTable_ID) happens outside of the transaction which inserts into the source table (which I learned from an excellent answer by Paul White [on the related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/can-i-rely-on-reading-sql-server-identity-values-in-order), but judging by the time stamps in both tables this scenario seems highly unlikely.

The question is:

How likely is it that the missing row was invisible to the SELECT statement because its' identity was allocated outside of the inserting transaction and before the lock was acquired, given the fact that the next row in the batch (2141) was inserted into the source table a couple of seconds later but was successfully picked up?

We're running on Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16) (KB5011644) - 15.0.4223.1 (X64)

Comment: Why are you using `WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK, INDEX(PK_SrcTable))` in the first place? READ COMMITTED is the default, unless you use SNAPSHOT ISOLATION in the database. Forcing an index is more likely to lead to worse performance than what the query optimizer would choose. The optimizer knows the kind of data stored in the tables and indexes and can create far better execution plans than developers that based their assumptions on test data

Comment: How do you determine the `@FromID` value, and why is `@ToID` used? It would be enough to use `SrcTableID > @LastID` where `@LastID` is the `MAX(DestTable_SrcTableID)` value in the destination table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the rest of the code runs in snapshot isolation level to reduce blocking,  hence READCOMMITTEDLOCK hint on this clause. And the index is a clustered PK , which in this case gives optimal performance.

Comment: the jobs runs a WHILE loop, loading fixed-sized batches, so at first iteration `@FromID=MAX(DestTable_SrcTableID)+1` and `@ToID=@FromID+ @BatchSize - 1` .  And these values are logged, so I know exactly what was the select statement that executed. in this example the values were 2140 and 2566 respectively.

Comment: Is it always the first row in a batch?

Comment: @Charlieface - no, it can be anywhere in the batch. But it is always a single row.

Comment: Are there only ever inserts on this table? Have you considered using a higher isolation level such as `REPEATABLEREAD`?

Comment: @Charlieface , yes , there are only inserts, and no, I have not considered `REPEATABLEREAD` since I'm not sure how it is supposed to solve the issue.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you probably want either `SNAPSHOT` or `SERIALIZABLE` to guarantee that you only ever see all rows or none. I would say `SNAPSHOT` probably works better: that combined with a `rowversion` column (compare each row to `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()`) would probably be the ideal way to keep rows in sync transactionally. See also https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-repeatable-read-isolation-level